# Selecting specific span to show user input

Tags: jquery

i have this code which creates div dynamically onclick of a button. Within div created, will ask for user input and submit. On submit, it will show the input in the same div, then create another div which will do the same thing. The shown value should stay in each div and every div should only show it's related input.

```
var i=1;
$(document).ready(function(){     
   $("#addCase").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    //adding div
    var idName ="Div_num_"+i;   
        $('.newValue').show(); 
        $('<div />').attr({
          'id' : idName       
          }).appendTo('#container').load("content.php", function() {   
              $('<h3>'+idName+'</h3>').prependTo($(this));    
            }); 
      i++;
    //showing input
      var $form = $("#addCase"),
      url = $form.attr("action"),      
      textInserted=$("#name").val();    
      $.post(url,function(){
        $(".insertedText").append(textInserted);   
      });
      $("#inputText").remove();
   });   
});
```

html :

```
<form id="addCase" method="post" action="">
  <div id="container"></div>
  <input id="addNew" type="submit" value="Add Case">        
</form>
```

content.php

```
<div id="inputText"><p>Text :<input name="name" id="name" type="text"/></p></div>
<div style="display:none;" class="newValue"><p> Inserted Text :<span class="insertedText"></span></p></div>
```

I don't know how to select related span, so that the new value inserted only will be shown only in it's place.

Can someone pls show me how to do it proper. Thank you in advance for any help.

eg.
   1st input = A, 2nd input = B
, result now :
   div#1 show AB and div#2 show B
, result should be :
   div#1 show A and div#2 show B

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question exactly, but if you want to display the input text and nothing else, just change append() to html() and it will set the content of the corresponding element to what you provide in the parameter and all other content inside the element will be removed.

Comment: i'm sorry for not being clear. The div created dynamically on click button. In each div created it will ask for user input, and when a value inserted and submit, another div will be created and the new value should be shown in the previous div.The problem is : the value inserted are added into all span in every div created (eg. input1+input2 in div#1, input2 in div#2), while actually i only want to show each value for each span in each div. (eg. input1 in div#1, input2 in div#2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)  instead of [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/), if you need to show the inserted value only...

[html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) is used to set an element's content, any content that was in that element is completely replaced by the new content

[append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) inserts content, specified by the parameter, to the end of each element in the set of matched elements.

```
....
$.post(url,function(){
   $(".insertedText").html(textInserted);   //here
});
```

....

**UPDATED**

```
var i=1;
$(document).ready(function(){     
$("#addCase").submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault(); 
//adding div
var idName ="Div_num_"+i;   
    $('.newValue').show(); 
    $('<div />').attr({
      'id' : idName       
      }).appendTo('#container').load("content.php", function() {   
          $('<h3>'+idName+'</h3>').prependTo($(this));    
        }); 

//showing input
  var $form = $("#addCase"),
  url = $form.attr("action"),      
  textInserted=$("#name").val();    
  $.post(url,function(){
    $("#"+ idName).find(".insertedText").html(textInserted);   //updated here 
  });
  $("#inputText").remove();
  i++;  //increment to the end
});   
});
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but i need to show each value inserted in each div created.

Comment: I edited my question, and with your suggestion, all value in every divs created are replaced by new input.I need each value to stay in each div.

Comment: bipen, it still not working, as values inserted are not showing. thanks for the update btw.

Comment: tht should work .. try replacing `$("#Div_num_"+i+".insertedText")` with `$("#Div_num_"+i).find(".insertedText")`

Comment: it works now, using your last suggestion, but after i added new variable, var a=i-1, then use it in $("#Div_num_"+a).find(".insertedText"). Thank u so much bipen :)

Comment: same to you, ..happy new year.. ;)